# What does 'disk box' mean here?

Tags: terminology, ambiguity, technical

[image: What is a 'disk box' here?]

The expression is mentioned under the number 1 of the list at the bottom of the picture.
The search over the internet hasn't given me a more or less clear idea of what it could be for it to match the context. Please, help.

Comment: Presumably your device (whatever it is) has no box for a disc. Without knowing anything else about the context, it's possible only to comment on the plain meaning.

Comment: for which device you got these instructions?

Comment: It´s a DVD player.

Comment: The problem is that the context is all here. And I can´t say I see any connection between a disk box as a box for a disk and shortcuts or touch operations... I wouldn´t say it´s obvious that the device HAS a disk box. Why would they put it down here? That is why I´m asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It is just poorly translated from the Chinese term for Hard Disk.

In Simplified Chinese, `Yìngpán` means `hard disk`.  Using Google translation, `disk box` literally translates to `Yìngpán hé`.

In short, the instruction just means that **your device does not contain a hard disk**.  The original instruction was probably in Chinese and then localized to English.

Comment: Note that it says _disc box_ (not _disk box_), which Google correctly translates as 光盘盒. The reverse translations give _hard disk box_ and _CD case_, neither of which is what is found here. So if it is indeed a CN->EN translation error, I doubt the fault lies with Google Translate (for once).

Comment: Well spotted user82373 :-)